# Is there a way to use input to climb nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, input, nested

I started making a collection of all the recipes in the game Subnautica, initially using lists and later moving to nested dictionaries. With help from an acquaintance, I managed to make it possible to have the full list of all of the categories present, as shown below.

```
SRI #Subnautica Recipe Index

fabricator
mobile
habitat
vehicle
scanner
modification
cyclops
neptune

Enter a choice >
```

You input the name and it goes down into the next category and the next, until the recipe is shown:

```
Enter a choice > titanium #user input
1 metal salvage
```

My problem is I don't know how to get the input able to "climb" back up the categories/dictionaries if you happen to type the wrong one. Here is the code that allows to go down.

```
def dive(dict_):
    print()
    for key in dict_:
        print(key)
    input_ = input("\nEnter a choice > ")
    if input_ in dict_ and isinstance(dict_[input_], dict):
        dive(dict_[input_])
    else:
        print(dict_[input_])
```

I've looked for the solution, though I think my problem is rather specific. Google hasn't been much help, unless I've been using the wrong or too unspecific search terms. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along this idea? (untested)
Keep track of your parent path through the dict:

```
def dive(dict_, parents=[]):
    print()
    for key in dict_:
        print(key)
    if parents:
        print('back')
    input_ = input("\nEnter a choice > ")
    if input_ == 'back' and parents:
        dive(parents[-1], parents[:-1])
    elif input_ in dict_ and isinstance(dict_[input_], dict):
        dive(dict_[input_], parents+[dict_])
    else:
        print(dict_[input_])
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, as long you spell it out right the first time. =)